# DB2 a reference to column is ambigous

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I want to write a select to combine two result sets without using `union`.

**TABLE_A**

| ID | VALID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | false |

**TABLE_B**

| ID | VALID |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | true |
| 55 | false |

Can I make a `select` like this without using `union`

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B
```

With union...

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_B
UNION
```

expected result...

| ID | VALID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | false |
| 44 | true |
| 55 | false |

Comment: By which relationship do you want to join these 2 tables?  What you have written now is a cross join.

Comment: There is no relationship between this two tables. I only want to combine the resultset, take a look at the above example.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `UNION`? It seems like `UNION ALL` would be best here, but your use case is unclear.